# Check height, then add or remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a navigation responsive. When the width is above a number it should get a class, when it's below, the class should get removed:

```
var width = $("#primary-header-nav").width();
if ( width < 770) {
  $('#primary-header-nav li a').addClass('box-1-9');    
} else {
  $('#primary-header-nav li a').removeClass('box-1-9'); 
}
```

However, in reality, the class is never assigned. Regardless of the width.

This is the site if it is of any help: http://darylkeep.com/aanbod/

Comment: Are you running this with an event, like resize, or just when the page loads?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/resize/ May be worth a look if you're not already using this inside an event handler.

Comment: This is not how you make a site responsive...

Comment: try learning about CSS media queries, it's the way to accomplish this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Maybe I did not explain clearly enough. The problem is that when my menu gets below 770, it turns into a drop down menu like you always see on phones. This is okay, but the links in the drop down are only 1/9th of the page. This is because the dropdown shares the same classes as the regular full width menu. I'm only trying to make do with the plugins and php I have. Media queries _are_ in place.

I finished school last year but I'm currently in an internship where I have to produce websites within a certain timeframe. I'm long overdue because I'm not that skilled yet. I'm trying though ;)

Comment: Turns out it was much easier than I thought, my brain gets clogged sometimes. I'm sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(){
    $(window).on("resize", function(){

      var width = $(this).width();
      var links = $('#primary-header-nav li a');

      if(width < 770){
        links.addClass('box-1-9');
      }else{
        links.removeClass('box-1-9');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work but I found out how to make it work now. Points for your suggestion though, I did not know about this `resize` function yet and I'm sure it will be helpful in the future.